# Pegar o elemento pai no hover

Tags: css, css3

Bom Dia!
É possível alterar o elemento pai dando hover no filho?
Por exemplo, tenho o seguinte:

```css
nav {border:2px solid red}

nav ul li {color:#fff}

nav ul li a:hover {background-color:#ccc}

nav ul li a:hover nav {border:2px solid black}
```

```html
    <nav>
        <ul>
         <li> <a href="#">Teste</a> </li>
         <li> <a href="#">Teste</a> </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

Ao passar o mouse no `<a>`, quero que a `<nav>` mude a cor da borda.

Já li algo sobre não ser possível pegar o elemento pai e que isso estará disponível no css 4. Caso seja realmente verdade, como posso fazer isso por js?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Como você mesmo apontou, o pseudo seletor [`.has()`](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors-4/#has-pseudo) estará disponível apenas na versão 4, mas caso o mesmo já estivesse implementado nos Browsers, você poderia fazer o seguinte:

```
nav:has(> ul li a:hover) {
    border:2px solid black
}
```

porém você pode conseguir o efeito desejado aplicando o seguinte JS:

```js
var links = document.querySelectorAll("nav ul li a");
var nav = document.querySelector("nav");

var onLinkMouseEnter = function () {
    nav.classList.add("onNavHover");  
}

var onLinkMouseOut = function () {
    nav.classList.remove("onNavHover");
}

var onLinkMouseEnterDelay = function () {
    window.setTimeout(onLinkMouseEnter, 1);    
}

for (var indice in links) {
    var link = links[indice];
    link.onmouseenter = onLinkMouseEnterDelay;
    link.onmouseout = onLinkMouseOut;
}
```

```css
nav {border:2px solid red}

nav ul li {color:#fff}

nav ul li a:hover {background-color:#ccc}

.onNavHover {border:2px solid black}
```

```html
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li> <a href="#">Teste</a> </li>
        <li> <a href="#">Teste</a> </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Tive que usar o `window.setTimeout`, pois o `element.onmouseenter` estava sendo executado antes do `element.onmouseout`, desta forma ele passa a ser executado apenas depois do `element.onmouseout`.

Comment: Poderia ilustrar melhor a questão do pseudo seletor `.has()`? Levando em consideração que o CSS 4 já tenha sido implementado, como ele seria aplicado nesse contexto?

Comment: resposta atualizada.